# Get nodes based on various date rules

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get a list of nodes, based on 2 rules, both related to a date field (myDate in this example).

I currently have the following, that only takes one of the 2 rules, which is checking if the date field is empty;

```
var results = root.Descendants("myDocType") 
    .Where(x => !x.GetProperty("myDate").HasValue)
    .OrderBy("myDate desc");
```

In the same Where clause, i need to check for:

- The date is empty OR
- The date is today or earlier (just the date, not the time of day)

So i basically need to add the last requirement to my Where clause. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
var results = root.Descendants("myDocType")
   .Where(x => !x.GetProperty("myDate").HasValue 
             || x.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("myDate") >= DateTime.Now.Date)
   .OrderBy("myDate desc");
```